# How to find the second child node using XSLT and change the node name

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following  input xml . I need to do couple of steps to get the desired out put. I am not well versed in XSLT. I can do basic templates. I am stuck on the following task

I need to change `<WorkCompPolicyQuoteInqRq>` to `<WorkCompPolicyQuoteInqRs>`. The issue here is the name of the tag may vary it could be `<XXXYRq> <AbCRq>` But the position stays the same (the second child of `InsuranceSvcRq`)  and the last two characters are always "Rq".
I am not sure how to do this. I would appreciate any guidance. Thanks!

Input XML

```
<DATA>
   <SignonRq>
   </SignonRq>
   <InsuranceSvcRq>
      <RqUID>6D76AF16-56C0-4108-BD82-83985EDD6888</RqUID>
      <WorkCompPolicyQuoteInqRq>
         <RqUID>8CB1B8A1-83B2-4D94-8A9A-D5E801DD2E32</RqUID>
         <TransactionRequestDt>2012-12-26T12:14:18</TransactionRequestDt>
         <TransactionEffectiveDt>2012-10-01</TransactionEffectiveDt>
         <CurCd>USD</CurCd>
      </WorkCompPolicyQuoteInqRq>
   </InsuranceSvcRq>
</DATA>
```

Desired Output

```
<DATA>
   <Status>
      <StatusCd>0</StatusCd>
      <StatusDesc>ACORD Success</StatusDesc>
   </Status>
   <InsuranceSvcRs>
      <RqUID>6D76AF16-56C0-4108-BD82-83985EDD6888</RqUID>
      <WorkCompPolicyQuoteInqRs>
         <RqUID>8CB1B8A1-83B2-4D94-8A9A-D5E801DD2E32</RqUID>
         <TransactionRequestDt>2012-12-26T12:14:18</TransactionRequestDt>
         <TransactionEffectiveDt>2012-10-01</TransactionEffectiveDt>
         <CurCd>USD</CurCd>
         <MsgStatus>
            <MsgStatusCd>Error</MsgStatusCd>
            <MsgErrorCd>DataError</MsgErrorCd>
            <MsgStatusDesc>Request Failed</MsgStatusDesc>
            <ExtendedStatus>
               <ExtendedStatusCd>DataInvalid</ExtendedStatusCd>
               <ExtendedStatusDesc>Message</ExtendedStatusDesc>
            </ExtendedStatus>
         </MsgStatus>
      </WorkCompPolicyQuoteInqRs>
   </InsuranceSvcRs>
</DATA>
```

Comment: If the name of the element in question varies, then what is the rule for the new element name that is output?

Comment: The rule is replace the last character q in the string with s. For instance in the above example <WorkCompPolicyQuoteInqRq> will be written out as <WorkCompPolicyQuoteInqRs>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position criterion (the said element always the second child of `InsuranceSvRq`) is actually sufficient to identify this element. So, you do not have to also check if the last characters of the name are "Rq".

Write a template that matches a child of `InsuranceSvcRq` if it is in the second position:

```
<xsl:template match="InsuranceSvcRq/*[position() = 2]">
```

Then, introduce a new element whose name is the concatenation of almost the whole original name (without any potential namespace prefix) save for the last character - and "s" at the end.

```
   <xsl:element name="{concat(substring(local-name(),1,string-length() -1),'s')}">
```

Then, apply templates to the remainder of the document or do other things:

```
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

You might want to do something very similar with the `InsuranceSvcRq` element itself.

The rest of the changes from your input XML to the output are trivial. Since you clearly state:

> I can do basic templates.

I will leave them to you.